# TYPO3 9.5 Simple TMENU with broken Links

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

This simple TMENU https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/CreateAMenu/Index.html generates in my TYPO3 9.5 the expecting unordered list. The entries has also the correct site titles, but the links are all pointed to the Site Root /

**Anybody knows why?**

```
    <ul class="level1">
        <li><a href="/">Über uns</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Leistungen</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Standorte</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Karriere</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
```

> **UPDATE: The reason was that all slug fields were empty.**

Comment: I assume your installation has problems to render links at all. are the slugs of all that pages computed correctly? are other links to pages (inside of RTE-text or link fields) rendered correctly?

Comment: Your right. My slugs are emtpy, because I got an error for the Upgrade Wizard "Introduce URL parts ("slugs") to all existing pages": 

No pseudo-site found in root line of page 1884.

The page 1884 is a Page Translation. A normal Site Configuration exists.